# How to see if a tag exists within a specific section when parsing XML with Cheerio.js?

Tags: javascript, xml, cheerio

I've been parsing XML with Cheerio.js and I'm having issues with when Authors don't have the "ee" tags, because it will apply the next visible "ee" tag to it, resulting in a title with a mismatched link.

My question is, how do I ensure that an "ee" tag exists for only that title (so within that specific "info" or "hit" tag), and if it doesn't exist use the "url" tag instead (or assigns a dead link)?

Below is the Javascript code I've been using, with the XML after it. The first entry has an "ee" tag, while the second one only has a "url" tag.

```
    $('info').each(function(i, element) {
        var title = $('title').eq(i).text();
        var year = Number($('year').eq(i).text());
        if ($('ee').eq(i).length)
            var url = $('ee').eq(i).text(); 
        //Within this condition we can add each string to their respective cell
        if (year >= q.tenure) {
            //add entry to homepageII, authorFilter, & titleFilter
            homepage("#"+year).append("<tr><td><a href="+url+">"+title+"</a>").text();
            authorFilter("#"+q.tag).append("<tr><td><a href="+url+">"+title+"</a>").text();
            titleFilter("#titles").append("<tr><td><a href="+url+">"+title+"</a>").text();
            console.log(title);
            console.log(year);
            console.log(url + '\n');
        }
    });

<hit score="1" id="111111">
    <info>
        <authors>
            <author>Not Real Name</author>
            <author>Not Real Name</author>
            <author>Not Real Name</author>
        </authors>
        <title>
            Not Real Name
        </title>
        <venue>Not Real Name</venue>
        <volume>21</volume>
        <number>3</number>
        <pages>151-159</pages>
        <year>2014</year>
        <type>Journal Articles</type>
        <key>Not Real Name</key>
        <ee>The link I usually use</ee>
        <url>alternative link I could use</url>
    </info>
    <url>URL#111111</url>
</hit>
<hit score="1" id="1111111">
    <info>
        <authors>
            <author>Not Real Name</author>
            <author>Not Real Name</author>
            <author>Not Real Name</author>
            <author>Not Real Name</author>
            <author>Not Real Name</author>
        </authors>
        <title>
        Not Real Name
        </title>
        <venue>Not Real Name</venue>
        <volume>20</volume>
        <number>4</number>
        <pages>208-220</pages>
        <year>2013</year>
        <type>Journal Articles</type>
        <key>Not Real Name</key>
        <url>alt link I could use, no ee above</url>
    </info>
    <url>URL#11111111</url>
</hit>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to match the selected tags `<title>` `<year>` `<ee>` by their index inside of "parallel" arrays (that is, using the `.eq(i).` trick, you should better extract the interesting tags from inside each of `<hit> <info>` tags, individually.

Something similar to ...

```
let $infos = $('hit info');
$infos.each(function(i, element) {
  let $info = $(element);
  let title = $info.find('title').text().trim();
  let year = Number($info.find('year').text());
```

and then you might easily check if an individual `'<hit> <info>'` has an `<ee>` tag inside

```
  let ee = $info.find('ee').text();
  let url = ee ? ee : $info.find('url').text();     

  console.log(i,title,year,url);
});
```